# value returned from a function with a const range as arguments

Tags: c++

lets say I have a function

```
auto found = find(first, last, condition);
```

This find should be able to promise not to modify first to last.

So something like

```
auto find(const T* first, const T* last, Comp c = less<>);
```

results in a const T or const T* being returned.

so

```
int arr[] = {3, 4};
std::vector v(arr, arr +2);
int* found = find(v.begin(), v.end());
** error found is non-const.
```

I want to modify *found! What are my options?  overloads?

Comment: `const* T first` isn't valid syntax, seems like you mean `T const* first`.  But if `T` is a template parameter as it sounds, the `const` (or lack thereof) can be buried inside of `T`...

Comment: You want to forbid regular iterator, and require const_iterator?

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'd like to provide constness even with templates.

Comment: @Jarod42 I want to improve constness.

Comment: Have you access to C++20 (with concept or `std::span<const T>`), else SFINAE might be the way to go.

Comment: @Jarod42 I do. Else SFINAE will still provide the compiler with the (first, last) being non-const.  That's probably the answer I'm looking for. I was hoping for another answer=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have that signature

```
int* my_find(const int* begin, const int* end);
```

(to signaling that your method doesn't modify the range)
without (dangerous) `/*const_*/cast`.

That signature would allow

```
const int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

*my_find(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr)) = 42; // Modifying const object. -> UB
```

Possibility would be, at the call site, to do all the casting:

```
// const int* my_find(const int*, const int*);
int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

auto it = const_cast<int*>(my_find(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr)));
```

That assumes though that returned pointer is in range, and not pointer on external const object (signatures can't ensure that (Rust has additionally lifetime in type which enforces a little more that assumption :) )).

Comment: It would be nice to be able to wrap that cast in an overload. alas here we are. Thanks for your input.